# How do I get visual studio code auto-import, etc. to work when I have lots of typings files?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I recently upgraded my Angular 4 project to Angular 5, and my typescript library from 2.3.4 to 2.5.3. Now whenever I open my project in visual studio code I get the warning pop-up:
"To enable project-wide Javascript/Typescript language features, exclude large folders with source files that you do not work on."

I have already excluded node_modules and my build folders, but I still get this warning. Features like auto-import aren't working and I'm assuming it's because of this error. This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types/"
    ],
    "types": [ "node", "angular", "jasmine" ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "**/node_modules/*",
    "**/dev/*",
    "**/prod/*",
    "**/bower_components/*",
    "**/*-aot.ts"
  ],
  "outDir":"build"
}
```

I enabled verbose logging in visual studio code, and it shows tons of typings file being included from node_modules, but no actual source. There are about 700 lines that have my source files, and lots of files like this:

```
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/material/material.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/index.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/material/material.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/browser_xhr.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/enums.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/headers.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/body.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/static_request.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/url_search_params.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/interfaces.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/base_response_options.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/static_response.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/jsonp_backend.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/base_request_options.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/http.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/http_module.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/version.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/index.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/public_api.d.ts
c:/[PATH]/node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/browser_jsonp.d.ts
```

What configuration do I have wrong? How do I get this annoying error to stop popping up and for the typescript features to work properly now in visual studio code?

Comment: Are you using TypeScript 2.5 in your VS Code workspace to power the language features, or are you using the built-in TypeScript version?

Comment: I've got it setup to use Typescript 2.5.3, the one from my workspace. I can see in the bottom info bar that it says it's using Typescript 2.5.3 as well.

Comment: You should trying upgrading, or at least change the workspace to use TS 2.9+. There have been a number of bug fixes since 2.5

Comment: I can try that, but I'm working on a web project, so I have a dozen or more other libraries dependent on the typescript library, so if I upgrade typescript I have to be careful it's compatible with all my other libraries. Ugh, typescript is such a nightmare to work with.

Comment: Now I no longer get the error, but the auto-import suggestions are still not working. Maybe the problem is not with the excludes and with something else? I don't need to turn on auto-import suggestions in settings do I?

Comment: Upgrading TS versions will usually not break anything. Are you still seeing the prompt about excluding files on TS 2.9?

Comment: I didn't upgrade to TS 2.9 yet because it's such a big undertaking to do that when I have so many dependent libraries. I added a jsconfig.json to my project with an ignore for my bower components folders, since I have a hybrid Angular/angularJS project and I still have a lot of bower components from the angularJS left over, and now I haven't seen the warning in a day. My imports still don't work though.

Comment: I tried upgrading to TS 2.9 and it slowed my build down to a crawl. Normally it takes about 30 seconds to build (TS 2.5.3) once I updated to 2.9 it took over 5 minutes. I don't know how long it would actually take, I killed it after 5 minutes. TS 2.9 is definitely unusable though.

Comment: It worked for me by changing the typescript version from the bottom left corner and also "exclude": ["**/node_modules/*","**/dist/**"] in tsconfig